# Migration from vba to vb.net - correct logic for using Iserror

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I'm trying to use this code:

```
If Not IsError(Convert.ToDateTime(DatiBase(i).innertext.substring(DatiBase(i).innertext.indexof(":") + 1).trim(), New CultureInfo("it-IT"))) Then
    MyString = "'" & Convert.ToDateTime(DatiBase(i).innertext.substring(DatiBase(i).innertext.indexof(":") + 1).trim(), New CultureInfo("it-IT")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
Else
    'Do something else
End If
```

My goal is to assign value to "MyString" only if "Convert.ToDateTime" gives a valid value but the code doesn't do that: It stops when the String isn't recognized as a valid DateTime instead of execute the "else" code.

Comment: DateTime.TryParse, DateTime.TryParseExact. Forget the old VBA/VB6 code and use the library

Comment: @Steve I'm not able to do right choice between `DateTime.TryParse Method (String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)` and `DateTime.TryParse Method (String, DateTime)`. My date string is always in italian style (`day/month/year`) but may be very different each time (`01/12/2014` or `1/12/14` or `01/12/14` or `01/12/2014 10:30` and so on)

Comment: You should have at least a set of possible formats and then use it for your conversion. I will provide an answer with some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanna thank Leonardo for the tip. This is the code I successfully used:

```
Dim culture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT")
Dim DateResult As DateTime
Dim styles As DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.None
Dim mTmpDate As String

mTmpDate = DatiBase(i).innertext.substring(DatiBase(i).innertext.indexof(":") + 1).trim()

If DateTime.TryParse(mTmpDate, culture, styles, DateResult) Then
    MyString = "'" & DateResult.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") & "'"
Else
    'Do something else
End If
```

The code works with any kind of date in "italian style" and in "MyString" I get a date/time formatted as mySql needs (for a timestamp field).

Answer (score 0):

You should use DateTime.TryParse:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I tryed to use this but it wasn't good because I don't know the style of dateTime string (it is variable)

Comment: I apologize. I've tryed ParseExact. Now I'm trying TryParse ... (I'm very new to vb.net)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know exactly what is the format in which you receive your string then you need to provide a set of possible formats to the DateTime.TryParseExact.

This example below is a simplified test version of your code above

```
Sub Main
    Dim dateConverted as DateTime
    Dim testDate = "asdfasldka:08/05/2015 13:10"
    Dim yourWannaBeDate = testDate.Substring(testDate.IndexOf(":") + 1).Trim()
    Dim possibleFormats = new string() {"d/M/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy H:m", "d/M/yy", "d/M/yy H:m"}
    if DateTime.TryParseExact(yourWannaBeDate, possibleFormats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dateConverted) then
        Console.WriteLine(dateConverted.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Not a date")
    End if
End Sub
```

The above code will match "08/05/2015", "8/5/2015", "08/05/15" and the same strings with the time part in two or one digit format

The trick consists in passing an array of possible formats that could be used to interpret the date in your CurrentCulture (I am assuming that your PC has the culture that match the formats above, however, if this is not the case just initialize a new CultureInfo variable and use it in the TryParseExact)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried but I don't feel master of this coding way. I'll keep trying to learn more (I make it working on .net fiddle but not in my project and I don't know why) but, at the moment, my questions are: 1) is it a so bad way to use "convert.toDateTime", because that automatically adjusts the date?; 2) How can I intercept failed conversions?

Comment: Yes it is bad. Convert.ToDateTime fails with an exception if it cannot interpret your date. Trapping the exception and trying to resolve with another Convert is like falling down in spiral inside a hole. Also if you manage to get it right the performances would be horrible. Given the numerous formats that you expect to handle the only way I could imagine is through DateTime.TryParseExact. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your tips and your time. After many attempts I was able to write a working code using "DateTime.TryParse" that seems not to need indication of original date format. However, I will continue to study and keep in mind your advice.